# How to get stacking layout in Regolith Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, i3, regolith

I just installed Regolith on top of a normal Ubuntu installation.

After some conflicting advice between the on-screen help and wiki (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, not <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>) I managed to toggle between vertical, horizontal and tabbed layouts. It skips the other standard layout option in i3wm, which is stacking.

How do I get a stacking layout in Regolith?

Answer (score 1):

After copying the file `/etc/regolith/i3/config` into `.config/regolith/i3/config`,
find the line:

```
bindsym $mod+$i3-wm.binding.layout_mode layout toggle tabbed splith splitv
```

Add **`stacking`** to it by:

```
bindsym $mod+$i3-wm.binding.layout_mode layout toggle tabbed stacking splith splitv
```

After saving and closing the file,
press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to reload i3:

Now, you can toggle the different layouts using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>;
press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> multiple times
(based on the number of layouts you have) until you see the stacking layout.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing it just like AbdElaziz Saad mentioned, ie. changing the `$mod+$i3-wm.binding.layout_mode` mapping in the `.config/regolith/i3/config` file.
However, one thing I disliked about that, if regolith makes any changes to `/etc/regolith/i3/config`, you won't see it unless you manually check it every once in a while.

(and that file has indeed changed a few times. Perhaps mainly due to the regolith 2.0 migration)

So what I'm doing now instead on regolith 2.0 is:

- There's a folder for putting your custom i3 config files: `~/.config/regolith2/i3/config.d/`

  - Nothing magical here, it's specified at the end of `~/.config/regolith2/i3/config`:

    ```
    # Include any regolith i3 partials
    include /usr/share/regolith/i3/config.d/*

    # Include any user i3 partials
    include $HOME/.config/regolith2/i3/config.d/*
    ```
- Add a file there with any name (mine is `~/.config/regolith2/i3/config.d/custom-i3`) containing:

```
workspace_layout stacked
```

What this does is make it so that any new windows will open with "stacked" layout by default, which means:

- all of my windows are stacked
- I never need to press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> unless I want to change that to tabbed
- Any updated to the default i3 config are not shadowed by my manual changes

Answer (score 0):

The Regolith i3 config is stored at `/etc/regolith/i3/config`. You can review it and then copy it to `.config/i3/config` in your home directory.

From there, using standard i3 config file syntax found in the user's manual to bind the keys you want to toggle stacking mode on.